# Syncfusion gantt chart add task progress value validation is having issue

Tags: angular, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I am working on an angular project which is using syncfusion ejs. In gantt chart view I am trying to add a new task there. When the add task dialogue opens I see a input box for progress. Progress is a number field. I have added validation required to that field.

[image: required pop up]

But when I type in something it is not going away. Also this only comes when I submit the form. But I want it to appear when I remove all data since it is required. There is another field Name that has the same required property and working fine. For this number field it is not working. What may the solution for this?

[image]

I added column settings to the gantt chart in syncfusion ejs but the required popup is not behaving as expected.